# Disabling basic auth causing 403 Access Denied Error in Spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a springboot2 app which doesn't have the basic-auth enforced but has the restriction on other endpoints.
I am seeing even with the valid user role I am getting 403 error when invoked from jenkins for

Http POST   http://xxxx:8085/myapp/actuator/shutdown

```
Response to shutdown request was 

{"timestamp":1602006760226,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access 
Denied","path":"/myapp/actuator/shutdown"}
```

This works when I tried through rest client with valid userid/role

Here is my WebSecurityConfig file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSEALSecurityConfig
{

    @Value("${ldap.server.admin.group}")
    private String SERVER_ADMIN_GROUP;

    @Value("${myapp.user.group}")
    private String APP_USER;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
    {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole(SERVER_ADMIN_GROUP)
                .antMatchers("/customer/deleteUser").hasRole(APP_USER)
                .and().addFilterBefore(getWinAuthenticationSelectionFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .httpBasic()
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

I have a AccessDeniedHandler class to capture 403 errors when user hits these restricted urls.

May I know what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, 403 error code indicates insufficient privileges.

Are you sure these instance variables are initialized correctly?

```
@Value("${ldap.server.admin.group}")
private String SERVER_ADMIN_GROUP;

@Value("${myapp.user.group}")
private String APP_USER;
```

For the url: *http://xxxx:8085/myapp/actuator/shutdown*, the following rule comes into action: *.antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole(SERVER_ADMIN_GROUP)*.

So, you will face issues if *SERVER_ADMIN_GROUP* is not properly initialized.